# Where can I get a machine readable representation of world currencies and their symbols?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, internationalization

I'm using ASP.Net and would like to display currencies based on a country.

I've had a look at http://www.xe.com/symbols.ph, http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php and http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/currency_codes/currency_codes_list-1.htm

Is there anywhere I can get something that I can load into a database? Or is there something built in to SQL Server 2005/ASP.Net to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.isocurrencysymbol%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that, I ended up having to do some LINQPad trickery for code generation to insert all that into the database, but thankfuly I didn't need to build a full XML document.